# Following java function is not inserting data into database,

Tags: java, mysql

I have created this function to take hashmap string, the string value, and table_name
how to call this function in my controller to insert into the database.

```
 public void insert_record(HashMap<String, String> dataMap, String tableName) throws SQLException {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO ").append(tableName).append(" (");
        StringBuilder placeholders = new StringBuilder();

        for (Iterator<String> iter = dataMap.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            sql.append(iter.next());
            placeholders.append("?");

            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                sql.append(",");
                placeholders.append(",");
            }
        }

        sql.append(") VALUES (").append(placeholders).append(")");

        PreparedStatement PreparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        //System.out.println(PreparedStatement);
        int i = 0;

        for (String value : dataMap.values()) {
            PreparedStatement.setObject(i++, value);
        }


        int affectedRows = PreparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    }
```

Comment: Don't patch together queries. They should be static. It is bad practice to do what you are trying.

Comment: then what would be a  good alternate .? i am confused.

Comment: Use a predefined query for every table, select, insert, ... Don't make one general query in which you put the table name.